Unable to access Acumatica ERP API
I’m not able to access the Acumatica API, through Postman and also Power Automate
Tried with both OAuth2.0 and Standard Authentication.
Our company creates solutions for data integration and automation hence we're using Acumatica ERP as a developer.
Acumatica ERP version 22.110.0018
curl --location 'http://23.19.244.91/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/20.200.001/Customer?%24select=CustomerName&%24top=10'

I did try with other entities like Ledger, PurchaseReciept, Invoice and also SalesOrder. Still this issue persists with these entities.
I've also tried changing the port number to 7008 as my server was using default port 80 for Acumatica ERP. But it didn't change anything with API.
Here is the complete error:
{
"message": "An error has occurred.",


"exceptionMessage": "Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.",


"exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXDatabaseException",


"stackTrace": " at PX.Data.PXSqlDatabaseProvider.ExecuteReaderInternal(IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n at PX.Data.PXSelectResult.PXSelectResultEnumerator.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n at PX.Data.PXView.GetResult(Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, Boolean reverseOrder, Int32 topCount, PXSearchColumn[] sorts, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter)\r\n at PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows)\r\n at PX.Data.PXDelayedQuery.GetRows(Boolean singleRow)\r\n at PX.Data.PXResultset`1.get__List()\r\n at PX.Data.PXResultset`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.Metadata.MetadataProvider.b__3_0()\r\n at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.prefetchMethod[t](PrefetchDelegate`1 prefetchDelegate, PXDatabaseSlot slot)\r\n at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.c__DisplayClass29_0`1.b__3(PXDatabaseSlot slot)\r\n at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()\r\n at PX.Data.PXDatabaseProviderBase.GetSlot[ObjectType](String key, PrefetchDelegate`1 prefetchDelegate, Type[] tables)\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.Metadata.MetadataProvider.TryGetMapping(String fieldMappingKey)\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.ExtensibilityHelper.CreateProjection(EntityFieldDescription entityFieldDescription, EntityEndpoint[] endpointExtensionChain, String fieldMappingKey, Func`2 mappingLocator, Func`2 postProcessor, Func`2 getEntityById, Func`4 getEntityFromEndpointByName)\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.Metadata.MetadataProviderExtensions.CreateProjection(IMetadataProvider metadataProvider, EntityEndpoint[] endpointExtensionChain, EntityFieldDescription entityFieldDescription, String fieldMappingKey)\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.ExtensibilityHelper.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__17`2.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportHelpers.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityExportContextBuilder..ctor(String version, String name, IMetadataProvider metadataProvider, IEntityMappingKeyService entityMappingKeyService, EntityImpl entity, IScreenInfoProvider screenInfoProvider, ISystemContract systemContract, PXGraph graph)\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.SoapFacade.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()",


"innerException": {

"message": "An error has occurred.",

"exceptionMessage": "Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.",

"exceptionType": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException",

"stackTrace": " at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()\r\n at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()\r\n at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)\r\n at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)\r\n at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)\r\n at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n at PX.Data.PXSqlDatabaseProvider.ExecuteReaderInternal(IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)",

"innerException": {

"message": "An error has occurred.",

"exceptionMessage": "The wait operation timed out",

"exceptionType": "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception",

"stackTrace": null

}

}

}

I was able to access them before, and It's been above 6 days this issue has started.
Also, could you please provide me with a solution to increase the performance of Acumatica web.

It looks like your job timed out in the database.  Meaning whatever processing you triggered took longer than the timeout value.  That generally means that you have a resource issue with your database.  Alternatively you could explore changing the timeout value for your database engine

Try increasing database connection string timeout in Acumatica instance web.config file:
<connectionStrings>
    <add providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" Connection Timeout=7200" ... />
</connectionStrings>

And increase Acumatica Query Timeout:
<add name="PXSqlDatabaseProvider" type="PX.Data.PXSqlDatabaseProvider, 
PX.Data" queryTimeout="300" ... />

You can use Acumatica Request Profiler or SQL Server Profiler to look up the generated SQL request for the web service call. Filter profiler results on BAccount (Customer table). Once you locate the problematic query you can apply standard database optimization technique for SQL Server.
